# Why Eclipse give me an error when I insert this XML Soap request inside a String?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am pretty new in **SOAP web services** in Java and I have the following problem.

I have a method that create the **SOAP Envelop** for a **REQUEST**, this one:

```
String soapXml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:getConfigSettings><tem:login>name.surname</tem:login><tem:password>myPassword</tem:password><tem:ipAddress>192.120.30.40</tem:ipAddress><tem:clientVersion>1</tem:clientVersion><tem:lastUpdateTime>1</tem:lastUpdateTime></tem:getConfigSettings></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
```

As you can see I put the **SOAP REQUEST Envelop** inside the **soapXml** string.

The problem is that when I put this XML inside this String object Eclipse marks this line as incorrect saying me the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Line breakpoint:WebServiceHelper [line: 124] - authentication(String, String, String, 
     String)
```

Is it an error concerning how I have inserted the XML code inside a String? Or what? What can I do to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are inserting contains `"`, terminating the initial string.

Escape every `"` as `\"` inside your SOAP string.

```
WRONG:
String soapXml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://sc ... to be continued       

CORRECT:
String soapXml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://sc ... to be continued
```

Comment: So before every " character I have to add the \ escape character? What exactly mean the escape character? it is sayng to Java that the next " character is not the end of a string but it is a " INSIDE the string?

Comment: Exactly. The escape character tells the java compiler, that the next character is either a special character (`\t` is TAB, `\n` is linefeed, `\r` is carriage return, `\uXXXX` is a unicode character with the code XXXX) or is to be taken as part of the string, like the `"`, which would normally terminate the string. To add a `\ ` in a string, you need to escape this, too. Because you need to tell the java compiler, you don't want the special meaning of the `\ `, you just want the character. So, `\ ` in a string is really `\\ ` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `"` inside the strings like this `\"`

```
String soapXml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:"+
"soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""+
"xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>"+
"<tem:getConfigSettings><tem:login>name.surname</tem:login>"+
"<tem:password>myPassword</tem:password><tem:ipAddress>192.120.30.40"+
"</tem:ipAddress><tem:clientVersion>1</tem:clientVersion>"+
"<tem:lastUpdateTime>1</tem:lastUpdateTime></tem:getConfigSettings>"+
"</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
```

More suitable example would be

```
String s = "hello";
String s2 = "\"hello\"";
System.out.println(s);      =>    hello
System.out.println(s2);      =>    "hello"
```